# laravel show users where last_seen <= 2 minutes

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

how can show users where last_seen column time <= 2 minutes with now()

i write this code but code cant calculate time

tip : last_seen column type is TimeStamp

```
$expiresAt = Carbon::parse(now())->addMinutes(2)->toTimeString();
    $users = User::where('is_admin', '!=', 'superAdmin')->whereNotNull('last_seen')->whereTime('last_seen', '<=', $expiresAt)->orderBy('last_seen', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Try remove orderBy

Comment: hi @Arthur . i remove orderBy  but again dosen't work and just show users where last_seen != null

Comment: Please show you last_seen format

Comment: You need to subtract the minutes, adding minutes is looking for people in the future and they cant be seen when the time hasn't elasped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$users = User::where('is_admin', '!=', 'superAdmin')
         ->whereNotNull('last_seen')
         ->whereDate('last_seen', '<=', now()->addMinutes(2))
         ->get();
```

It would be nice to have more information, are there any errors? show last_seen format

Comment: Hi @Arthur    no i dont have any error  and all time return back 2 user where last_seen != null  and query dont listen to whereDate and whereTime

Comment: this is result of query . i must use whereTime   . becuse i want to take time . not date

select * from `users` where `is_admin` != 'superAdmin' and `last_seen` is not null and time(`last_seen`) <= '03:26:13' and `users`.`deleted_at` is null

Answer (score 0):

ok i resolve this :D

wtf i must use subMinute
now this code is true

```
$users = User::where('is_admin', '!=', 'superAdmin')
        ->whereNotNull('last_seen')
        ->whereTime('last_seen', '>=', now()->subMinute(2))
        ->get();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).